# Im trying to make a acsess code for a app

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an access screen for an Android app where the user submitted an access code one time and then its saved to a file, on later starts the screen should be skipped and it should proceed directly into a later layout.

I'm not sure how to do all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Save your access code in SharedPreference and check if you have any. After that, you won't have any problem with that.

[SharedPreferences tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks in combination with other articales i found you answer was very usefull

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend the best way around. Whenever you are stuck on such things, Splash screen will help you. You can see on the splash screen I am checking if I have previously login or not and moving to another activity using that.

Let me explain how:-

Just make splash screen as Launcher activity. If you don't want that to display it for much longer, just have the handler run for 1-2 seconds. Now look at the code below.

> SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        //SharedPreference to Store API Result
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CachedResponse", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.apply();

        email = pref.getString("login", null);

        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

        if (email != null) {

            //It means User is already Logged in so I will take the user to Select_College Screen

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Select_College.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Email", email);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }

            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        } else {

            //It means User is not Logged in so I will take the user to Login Screen

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }

            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        }

    }
}
```

> Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_login);

        //SharedPreference to Store API Result
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CachedResponse", 0);

        Login();

    }

    private void login() {

        //If login is successfull, before moving to next activity, store something in sharedpreference with name login. It can be email or just a string as "true"

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.putString("login", email);
                        editor.apply();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(DoctorLogin.this, Select_Collage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Email", email);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

    }
}
```

> Select_Collage.java

```
public class Select_Collage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_message);

        //SharedPreference to Store API Result
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CachedResponse", 0);

        //Somewhere on Signout button click, delete the login sharedpreference
        signOut();

    }

    private void signOut() {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.remove("login");
        editor.apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Select_Collage.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

So that's how you can solve this problem. Keep Coding :)

Comment: I used a different method for this but i used the splash screen method to  make a loading screen, Thanks for the help!